# tf.Keras learning rate schedules—pass to optimizer or callbacks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, learning-rate

I just wanted to set up a learning rate schedule for my first CNN and I found there are various ways of doing so:

1. [One can include the schedule in callbacks](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/learning_rate_scheduler/) using `tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler()`
2. [One can pass it to an optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/LearningRateSchedule) using `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule()`

Now I wondered if there are any differences and if so, what are they? In case it makes no difference, why do those alternatives exist then? Is there a historical reason (and which method should be preferred)?

Can someone elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler()` and `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule()` provide the same functionality i.e to implement a learning rate decay while training the model.

A visible difference could be that `tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler` takes in a function in its constructor, as mentioned in the docs,

```
tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(schedule, verbose=0)
```

> **schedule**: a function that takes an epoch index (integer, indexed from 0) and current learning rate (float) as inputs and returns a new learning rate as output (float).

The `schedule` function will return a learning rate given the current epoch index. To implement various types of LR decays like the Exponential Decay, Polynomial Decay etc., you need to code them in this `schedule` method on your own.

On the other hand, `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule()` is a high-level class. Other types of decay included in `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.*` like the `PolynomialDecay` or `InverseTimeDecay` inherit this class. Hence this module offers builtin LR decay methods which are commonly used in ML. Moreover, to implement a custom LR decay, your class needs to inherit `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule()` and override methods like `__call__` and  `__init__`, as mentioned in the docs,

> To implement your own schedule object, you should implement the
> **call** method, which takes a step argument (scalar integer tensor, the current training step count).

**Conclusion:**

- If you want to use some built-in LR Decay, use `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.*` modules i.e. the LR decays provided in that module.
- If you need a simple custom LR decay which would only require the epoch index as an argument, use `tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler`.
- If your custom LR Decay needs more argument than just the epoch index, create a new class and inherit `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this explanation really helps for people who just get started with Tensorflow and Keras! It is sometimes hard to know where to start, given all the different possibilities.